# Tin Can API for Unity3D and Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, tin-can-api

I'm really new in C# and Unity, I need to build an Augmented Reality for Android and need a Tin Can Integration because it for Elearning purpose.

can anybody help me how to integrate Tin Can API into Unity?